# Разбить число на разряды Jinja2 (Python)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего разбить числа на разряды, которые рендерятся макросом в Jinja2? Чтобы вместо 12345 было 12 345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете написать для этого [фильтр](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#registering-filters)

```
import re
from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

thousand_separator = re.compile(r'[0-9](?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))')

@app.template_filter('thousands')
@evalcontextfilter
def add_thousand_separator(eval_ctx, value):
    result = thousand_separator.sub('\g<0> ', escape(value))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

И в шаблоне

```
{{ some_number|thousands }}
```

Comment: Для миллиона + не подходит, нужно править регулярное выражение?

Comment: И правда, не работает. Исправил.

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!